# Adobe AIR: save dialog with file type filter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Is that possible to add File type filter to save dialog ? I referred to [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class, it seems to be adding a file type filter to save dialog is not possible. It is available only for open dialog. Is there any other way to do this ?

I want a dialog as shown below:
[image: save dialog]

Comment: You can't, but you can suggest a file name `var docsDir:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("youfilename.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

> You can't, but you can suggest a file name:
>
> > var docsDir:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("youfilename.jpg");